# Bumping new questions to format, highlight or update context

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions, bumping

I tried to search past questions, to see if this was asked, and found one (of a similar nature) that does not address my problem [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much). Now we proceed with the question itself:

Is it okay to bump a new question (of your own) every few hours? If not, how often is acceptable. By bump, I mean to edit it in some way.

Does the answer remain the same if:

- The edits solely change the formatting in a way to improve the flow.
- The edits solely make it more apparent what the actual question is, in a large body of text.
- The edits solely revise, based on improved understanding. E.g. An attempt is made, and a slightly longer one can now be made. This does not include edits in which mistakes were corrected in the attempt.

The second part of this is of course frequency, but I am sure that is more subjective.

Comment: I think most people would consider the answer to be: no, no, no, yes. But I would be happy if it was: no, yes, yes, yes. $\color{white}{\textbf{BOO!}}$

Comment: Every few hours?  Wow.  My recommendation (for all questions, not only your own): limit yourself to at most three bumps per day.  (So, if you bump no other questions, then you can bump this one up to three times.)

Comment: Why did you add the line `$\color{white}{\textbf{DON'T GET SPOOKED!!!!!}}$` at the end of your post? To ruin the vertical spacing?

Comment: Downvote the main post if you don't think there is any reason to bump every few hours (for a new question).

Upvote this if you think at least one of the three dot points is permissible.

Comment: @Did Think of it, as a calling card my friend.

Comment: The notion of including a "calling card" in the body of a Question (or Answer) is similar to adding a "signature" and runs counter to the site's policies.  The idea is that your post is already linked to your profile and you can localize any personal information there.

Comment: We have bounties for a reason.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not alright to edit a new question every few hours for the sake of bumping it.

It is alright to make edits that genuinely improve the question. However, one is expected to make a reasonable effort to post a question in final form. That is, if everything goes according to plan, there should be no reason for edits a few hours after one posted originally.

That said, there is also no point in being overly self-censoring regarding edits. If something does not go according to plan and there is need for improvement, there is no reason to hesitate to perform it.

Finally, do not try to fake it. Placing intentionally shortcomings in your posts to have a ticket to edit and bump them later will likely backfire.

Comment: This sounds reasonable.