# Why does it take longer to click "$x$ questions with new activity" than to click "Questions" on the left?

Tags: bug

I have a pretty stable and fast enough internet connection, so I rule this out.

I use Firefox 63.0 on a Ubuntu machine.

When I click "$x$ questions with new activity" and the $x$ happens to be some integer in the $30$s or higher it takes really long until the new questions are displayed.

Now when I click just "Questions" on the left it loads in an instant.

Does this maybe have something to do with the fact that I display 50 questions per page?

Comment: Dear @AndrewOstergaard , please consider making fewer minor edits to old meta questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5070/21412

Comment: @KReiser When I made the edits, I wasn't thinking about the fact that those posts would be bumped. I will be sure to keep this in mind in the future. Thank you for taking the time to give me a helpful suggestion.